# Windows 7 auto log in when launching from a VM

Tags: windows-7, macos, virtual-machine, parallels

**Short Question**
Is there a way to configure Windows 7 to auto log on when launched as a virtual machine, but require a log in when boot natively (ie from Boot Camp?)?

**System Information**
Operating System(**s**):
Mac OS X Lion
Windows 7 Pro 64 bit

VM Software:
Parallels 7 + Boot Camp

**Current thoughts**
My gut it telling me this is not possible, however I would still like to know because logging in multiple times through out the day after I am already logged into OS X is becoming annoying.  Please note, I still want Windows to prompt if it is launched via Boot Camp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, not from the Windows side.  The benefit of a virtual machine is that the underlying OS **is not aware** that it is running in a VM in the first place.

VMware has to provide a paravirtualization capability (it sort of does, but mostly for I/O performance) in order for the guest OS to implement that functionality.

Comment: This is what I figured, but figured someone might have a found a way to tell a difference at boot.

Comment: You should petition VMware.  They update their device drivers as fast as an 800 lb gorilla.